# CSS Selectbox position absolute Bug IE10 + W8

Tags: html, forms, css, select, internet-explorer-10

IE10 got an weard selectbox error. When selected it flips to the top of page and flickers on/off. This problem only appears with IE10 and the "new" selectbox. Is it posible to force and show the old select box?

It seems like its going to CSS: position: fixed; top: 0px; something like that. Here is the cleaned up code and some screenshots:

[Link to screenshot](http://jxerot.com/share/bug.jpg)

CSS:

```
.div{
    border: 1px solid @BorderColor1; 
    margin: 0px 4px 0px 4px;
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
    position: relative;
}
 .popupselect{
    padding: 2px 0px 0px 4px; 
    width: 99px; 
    height: 37px;
    float:left; 
    background: @ButtonSprite;
    background-position: 0px -56px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 40px;
    left: 10px;
    display: none;
}

   .select{ width: 95px; }
   .div:hover .popupselect{display: block;}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="div">
                <div class="popupselect">
                    <select class="select">
                        <option value="">Aantal: 93821</option>
                        <option value="">Aantal: 112430</option>
                        <option value="">Aantal: 123</option>
                        <option value="">Aantal: 123</option>
                        <option value="">Aantal: 123</option>
                        <option value="">Aantal: 123</option>
                        <option value="">Aantal: 123</option>
                        <option value="">Aantal: 123</option>
                        <option value="">Aantal: 123</option>
                        <option value="">Aantal: 999</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
           </div>
```

Edit:
The display: none; to display: block; issn't working in IE10. A fix but not the most perfect one:

```
<script>
   if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE 10.0") !== -1)
      {document.documentElement.className += "ie10";}
</script>
.ie10 .popupselect{display:block;}
```

In this case the selectbox is always shown in IE10+ and hidden in all other browsers. The site now doesn't act the same on all browsers and I don't see this as an solution.

Comment: Consider posting this to http://connect.microsoft.com/IE as it appears to be a bug in IE. I second you BTW because I just saw a similar selection bug in IE 10 while trying to copy & paste some text from this Web page: http://sealedabstract.com/rants/why-mobile-web-apps-are-slow/ (please do not treat the URL as an ad or as spam; I am not affiliated with it in any way)